# How to best represent dynamic game actions in a REST API?

Tags: rest, post, dynamic, restful-url

I want to create a simple card game and put all the game logic server side. The client app will then interact with the backend via a REST API.

I have a part of it figured it out, however I'm struggling with how to implement dynamic actions with this kind of API.

For example, I have this kind of actions:

- Starting game
- Flipping card
- Checking user guess
- Pausing game
- Ending game

In particular, how would I deal with starting or pausing a game? I could do something like this:

```
POST /games/123/start
POST /games/123/pause
```

But that's not very RESTful since the last part of the URL would be a verb instead of a noun. Also, there's no data to actually POST.

How would I go about implementing this kind of dynamic actions? Any suggestion?

Comment: that should be fine if you have one more column to indicate game status, then you can use "games/123/status"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESTful APIs – where the verb is fully described by the HTTP method, and the resource is fully described by the URL – work best when your primary actions are CRUD, or think SQL (insert, select, update, delete). So think about how you could describe each of those actions in a CRUD-like manner:

- Starting a game is like creating one. It's started as soon as it's created:
  `POST /games`
- Pausing a game could be seen as moving a game into a "paused games" bucket:
  `PUT /games/paused/123`
- Ending a game is like deleting it:
  `DELETE /games/123`
  or at least like deleting it from the bucket of "active" games:
  `DELETE /games/active/123`

In the end it's up to you to design the API how best you see fit. Most real-world "RESTful" APIs are not 100% RESTful. At some point design purity must yield to pragmatism.

My recommendation: keep `GET`s, `PUT`s, `DELETE`s, etc. (everything that is not a `POST`) idempotent. `POST`s should be the *only* non-idempotent HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would recommend a route like:
`PUT /games/213`
with content:
`{game: {paused: false}}`

And if a game is not going then it's paused. I don't know what your model looks like, but I would imagine that all games would be created in a paused state and then I could run the request above to start it.

Also, `PUT` could be `POST`.

That's just my two cents.